# Custom RWD theme falling back on base theme instead of rwd

Tags: magento-1.9, rwd-theme, rwd, theme-fallback

I'm trying to create a custom RWD theme with magento 1.9 and for some reason even after following this guide:

https://www.flinttechnology.co.uk/customising-rwd-magento-responsive-theme/

Its using the base theme as the fallback instead of the RWD theme.
[image]

Comment: Can you add the contents of the theme.xml file to your question.  app/design/frontend/yourpackagename/yourthemename/etc/theme.xml

Comment: And full path where you have it located

Comment: What do you have in "Default" section in `system > configuration > design > theme` section?

Comment: @AdarshKhatri nothing, what should I have in there?

Comment: @ProxiBlue in theme xml it literally just says rwd/default, in app/design/frontend/mypackage/default/etc

Comment: The theme.xml should be a correctly formatted xml file. `<?xml version="1.0"?>
<theme>
    <parent>rwd/default</parent>
</theme>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

As @ProxiBlue pointed my mistake, you need to put this in your `theme/etc/theme.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
   <theme> 
     <parent>rwd/default</parent>
   </theme>
```

and have empty in `default` section, unless you have `default` theme in your theme package.

<strike>Things to understand of fallback of magento theme</strike>

You should have **RWD** in "Default" section of `system > configuration > design > theme`. This will make sure your theme will fallback to this theme.

**Points to remember**

1. When there is no required `.phtml` file exist in RWD theme, then it will again fall back to base theme.
2. Not all `.phtml` files exist in RWD theme, some of them extend from `base` theme.
3. **Same thing for `css or js or image` files**.

Hope this helps you.

More reading:

1. http://alanstorm.com/magento_infinite_fallback_theme_xml
2. http://www.classyllama.com/blog/depth-look-magento-theme-fallback

**Why there is no style applied?**

When it is falling back to base it tries to find those styles, since they don't exist there, it is unable to style your html. It totally make sense. Right click on browser and do inspect element, you will see those css/js/image files thrown as 404 not found error.

Comment: I started from scratch, installed compass and sass, followed the guide perfectly and now im just getting an unstyled page.

The guide doesn't tell you to copy of any of the CSS files from the rwd folder so I have no idea where I am going wrong here

Comment: Check this http://alanstorm.com/magento_infinite_fallback_theme_xml and this http://alanstorm.com/magento_parent_child_themes

Comment: Are you saying that I should be copying the CSS and JS aswell?

Comment: If you want to edit those files, then yes, otherwise no need to. Since it gonna fall back to RWD css/js anyway.

Comment: but it hasn't, when i dont copy the css and js over, it just shows as a unstyled page with just text

Comment: This means your theme still not falling back to RWD, you can just check your rendered html's source by doing "view source" in browser, this will tell you all the css and js files where are they called from.

Comment: its saying its getting them from base, but it is still completely unstyled, this makes absolutely no sense

Comment: When it is falling back to `base` it tries to find those styles, since they don't exist there, it is unable to style your html. It totally make sense. Right click on browser and do inspect element, you will see those css files thrown as 404 not found error.

Comment: that makes sense, but then why is it using base instead of rwd when i set the fallback to rwd

Comment: check my updated answer. also clear the cache.

Comment: YES!!!!! YOU FIXED IT

Comment: I have to query this statement: "You should have RWD in "Default" section of system > configuration > design > theme." This will make sure your theme will fallback to this theme" as that does not sound correct to me. as far as I know, this has nothing to do with the fallback, but notes the name of the theme of the current package.

Comment: As far as I am concerned, this answer is incorrect, and miss-information. The reason the theme was not doing the fallback, is due to the theme.xml not being properly formatted xml with fallback directives.

Comment: @ProxiBlue As I understand, having parent theme name in `default` section means telling magento to use this theme before falling back to base. You are welcome to add your own answer with correct xml.

Comment: @AdarshKhatri - that is just wrong. Can you point me to a resource that notes that as given functionality? The default is the name of YOUR theme in YOUR package. It has nothing to do with fallbacks. If you have nothing in that field, it will look for Default in YOUR package as the default. This allows you to place multiple themes, in a package, and set the default.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I gather your theme fallback xml is not correct.

The file should contain proper xml, with a `<parent>` directive.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
   <theme> 
     <parent>rwd/default</parent>
   </theme>
```

It looks like the resource you are working from has some issues with the display of the formatted xmlon their blog entry

This is most likely why you thought you only need to have the text 'rwd/default' in the theme.xml file, without any directives.

[image]

Comment: but in the end i did that before you ever even replied, not saying your wrong but my xml file is exactly like that now and still didnt fix it until i changed the settings in the magento config

Comment: Look i am not getting into a competition on who is right and who is wrong. Good luck with your site.

Comment: However, the fact that editing your theme settings as was suggested made it work most likely points to some other issue. Months from now you will most likely run into some other issues with theme files. Due to the incorrect setup youd most likely never figure out why. It is best you revert that. And figure out what is really wrong.

Comment: I wasn't arguing, was just saying that I edited the xml file as you stated and nothing changed until I changed the settings in magento. Infact I would love to know why my theme.xml file isn't making the changes I need as I would rather do things the correct way